# PHP callback - array or arrow syntax?

Tags: php

Let's assume we have this function

```
<?php
function run($callback)
{
    $callback($some, $params);
}
```

How to call it?

```
run($someObject->callback);
```

or rather

```
run([$someObject, 'callback']);
```

The first one seems better to me especially because of code suggestion but in documentation is used array notation.

Why is first one worse than second one?

Comment: Does the first one even work? It would only work if "callback" was a variable whose value was a function.

Comment: Use any of the methods described in the documentation of PHP [Callable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php)s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array notation is better because the arrow notation **doesn't work**. Functions in PHP aren't first class objects which can be passed around. Whenever you "pass a function", you must pass it by name; i.e. only its name. To pass an object method, you need to pass the object and the method name using the [`callable` pseudo type notation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php).